# How to convert the binary number 0.1011111... to fraction number

Tags: binary, fractions

Can the binary number 0.1011111..., i.e., 0.10(1) be represented as a fraction {a}/{b} with a and b integer numbers?

Answer (score 2):

0.1011111...<sub>2</sub>
      = 0.1111111...<sub>2</sub> - 0.01<sub>2</sub>
      = 1 - 0.01<sub>2</sub>
      = 0.11<sub>2</sub>
      = 3/4

If you're wondering how 0.1111111...<sub>2</sub> is equal to 1, see Wikipedia's article explaining why [0.999... = 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...).